# How to use custom class as Observable and fire method in time interval

Tags: java, observable, rx-java

I have a class `Producer`, simplifying it has method `public Object readData()`
I want to make this class as `Observable` ([RxJava](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/wiki/Observable)).

How to indicate which method should be called? Do I need transform my `Producer` class into `Future` or `Iterable`?

The next problem is that the `readData` should be call **every n seconds**.
Some methods, for instance [from](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/wiki/Creating-Observables#from), has scheduler parameter but I can not find any example how to apply it.
I found [interval](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava/wiki/Creating-Observables#interval) method, but it emits a sequence of integers.
So far, without Observable I use `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleWithFixedDelay(....)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still use the `interval()` method, just ignore its result!

```
final Producer producer = ...;
int n = ...;
Observable<Object> obs = 
    Observable.interval(n,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
              .map(new Func1<Integer,Object>() {
                  @Override
                  public Object call(Integer i) {
                      return producer.readData();
                  }
               ));
```

Answer (score 1):

I am new to RxJava, but nobody else has answered your question so here is a stab at it.

My suggestion is for your Producer class to implement the interface `Observable.OnSubscribeFunc` ([Javadoc](http://netflix.github.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.OnSubscribeFunc.html)). In the method `public Subscription onSubscribe(Observer<T> observer)`, you can call your `Producer#readData()` method to get what data is currently available and pass that data into the `onNext()` method, like this:

```
// Make sure to change T as appropriate
public class Producer implements OnSubscribeFunc<T> {
    . . . 

    @Override
    public Subscription onSubscribe(Observer<T> observer) {
        while (this.hasData()) {
            observer.onNext(this.readData());
        observer.onCompleted();
    }
}
```

(This assumes that your `Producer#readData()` method returns data in chunks rather than all at once. Tweak as needed.)

You can then subscribe to your Producer object using `Observable#create(OnSubscribeFunc<T>)` method, and also arrange to have your Observable return elements on a timer:

```
// In your observer class
Observable<T> myProducer = Observable.create(new Producer(...));

ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = 
        Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor().scheduleWithFixedDelay(....);
Observable<T> myProducerTimed = myProducer.subscribeOn(Schedulers.executor(scheduler));
// Now use myProducerTimed
```

I can't test those last two lines right now. Sorry, I'll look into that and update my answer if it changes things.

DISCLAIMER: I am an RxJava n00b, so this solution might suck or might be needlessly messy. Fix what seems wrong.

UPDATE: I had a problem ([RxJava -- Terminating Infinite Streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20663255/rxjava-terminating-infinite-streams)) with RxJava as well; looks like my solution will look a lot like yours (using the Scheduler to make the Observable return elements periodically).

Comment: My suggestion does all the heavy lifting in `onSubcribe()`. That is incorrect (see the SO question I linked to my answer), but I can't rework my answer at the moment. I welcome edits if someone gets to it before me.